# How can I install Ubuntu server 20.04 without grub

Tags: grub2, mac

I am trying to install ubuntu server 20.04.5 on mac mini late 2018

but installation crashed when installing grub

I tried to install ubuntu server with autoinstall, the grub section of autoinstall config is:

grub:
install_devices:
- /dev/nvme0n1p1
replace_linux_default: False
update_nvram:  False
terminal: console
probe_additional_os: False

but it failed too. (gpt, nvme0n1p1 - 200M, has boot flag)

I installed Ubuntu desktop 20.04.5 on mac mini without grub (from terminal run ubiquity -b), and after that install grub. It works.

How can I install ubuntu server 20.04 without grub?

Comment: Please explain again what you have and what you want. It seems to me that you already have what you want: "It works", unless you want it to work without grub. In that case: Why do you want it to work without grub?

Comment: I need to install Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 on mac mini - this is main goal.
But grub installation always fails. That's why I need to install  Ubuntu Server 20.04.5 without grub. And after that I will install grab

apt-get install grub-efi-amd64 -y

grub-install --uefi-secure-boot --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi boot-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB --no-nvram  --removable


sudo update-grub

Comment: Maybe it will work to extract and clone from a compressed image of Ubuntu Server. But I think there are only jammy alias 22.04.x LTS and the bleeding edge daily built lunar alias 23.04, soon replaced by the next version mantic alias 23.10. See [this link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692).